# Good way to remove unnecessary stuff from dashboard?

Tags: dashboard

To this day I have been using CSS to hide unneeeded stuff from the dashboard area in the backend of Wordpress. But I don't like this way as it is easy to make it visible again.
On things I have found a way, I have been using hooks to disable them.

But there are things I haven't managed to remove easily with hooks. For example the Primary Site selection under My Sites in a multisite network.

I found this way, which seems to remove it completely before site is loading.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'remove_from_my_sites' ) ) {
    function remove_from_my_sites( $subject ) {
    if (get_current_screen()->id == 'my-sites') {
        $subject = preg_replace('#<table class="form-table(.*?)</table>#s', '', $subject, 1);
    }
    return $subject;
    }
    function subject_start_my_sites() {
    if ( current_user_can('read') ) {
            ob_start( 'remove_from_my_sites' );
    }
    }
    function subject_end_my_sites() {
    if ( current_user_can('read') ) {
            ob_end_flush();
    }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'subject_start_my_sites' );
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'subject_end_my_sites' );
```

Is this a good way to remove stuff? Or will it reduce performance?
I want to know before I continue using this!

Comment: It's not a *great* way to remove stuff. You're essentially putting the whole page load on hold until everything is finished so that you can remove something before it's rendered. This will greatly reduce perceived performance as it will take longer than normal for anything at all to appear in the browser.

Comment: I was scared of that! But is there a better way to do this? I find it very hard to find some of the hooks to remove stuff from the dashboard.

Comment: Some stuff just doesn't have hooks. If a hook isn't available there's probably a reason why. Why do you need to remove this part of the admin?

Comment: I use Wordpress as a multisite network and there are a few things the admins will have no use for and that is just confusing for them. So I am simplifying the UI.